# How to set background color to an entire cell with some element in a condition using PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to set a background in my entire cell (or my entire row) according to my condition, but the background it placed only at my HTML element.

I already tried put some class at my  trying to set the padding 0, I already tried put some div.

HTML

```
<p-column header="Motivo"  [style]="{width: '100px', 'text-align': 'center'}">
  <ng-template let-movimento="rowData" pTemplate="body">
   <p [ngClass]="{'motivo-SemEfeito': movimento.motivoDesligamentoId == 2}">
       {{ movimento.motivoDesligamento }}
    </p>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

CSS

```
.motivo-SemEfeito {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background: red;
 }
```

Comment: I tried rowStyleClass but didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way by using `styleClass`

> HTML

```
<p-column header="Motivo"  [styleClass]="methodNameForTheClass(data)">
```

> TS

```
 methodNameForTheClass(data){
   // write your condion here and return class name as string
   return 'className';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shown in [the document of NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) you can put a condition to your class:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'first': true, 'second': true, 'third': false}">...</some-element>
```

Put the background in your css class for it:

html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'red': red, 'blue': !red}">
    <p-column header="Motivo"  [style]="{width: '100px', 'text-align': 'center'}">
      <ng-template let-movimento="rowData" pTemplate="body">
       <p [ngClass]="{'motivo-SemEfeito': movimento.motivoDesligamentoId == 2}">
           {{ movimento.motivoDesligamento }}
        </p>
      </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</div>
```

css:

```
.red {
    background: red;
}
```

ts:

```
const red = false;
```